# Nothing gets put into the database nor any message is sent. Have any ideas?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@commands.command()
async def Money(self, ctx, member:discord.Member):
    member = ctx.message.author.name
    member_id = ctx.message.author.id
    db = sqlite3.connect("main.sqlite")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT member_id FROM main WHERE member_id = {member_id}")
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        sql = (f"INSERT INTO main(member_id, money) VALUES(?,?)")
        val = (member_id, 500)
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit()
        await ctx.send("Because you didn't have an account, I just made one for you!")
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{member}'s Money", description = f"{result[1]} <:BitCoin:929595745500274689>", color = discord.Colour.random)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
```

Nothing gets put into the database nor any message is sent. The command seems to fail.

Comment: You could add logging to the function to get a better idea of what's going on. I notice you make synchronous sql calls in an async routine. Try the aiosqlite module or use a background thread for the sql stuff.

Comment: What do you mean by "Logging" How would I go about adding that?

Comment: This link nto async logging in the docs should help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#logging